# Update gridview to sql table all at once

Tags: sql, gridview, dataset

So I have a gridview in an ASP webpage that I want to periodically update all at once to the sql server.

Each cell consists of a textbox in a templatefield like so:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item" HeaderStyle-CssClass="pinnedcol" ControlStyle-Width="160px">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item") %>'
             ID="txtfocus" SelectedRowStyle="myselection" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have a timer set to update the sql server every 2 minutes, but I don't know how I should create an update command when the timer ticks. The table is quite large at 30 rows by 26 columns, so it seems impractical to compile a list of update statements that long. Is there a method that I  can invoke where it can track user modifications to the gridview and then update all at once to the sql server?

Answer (score 0):

If you use timer to update database it will call without any changes on your gridview. What I suggest it call your update method when updated happens on the gridview. You can use SQL DataSource with Update command and the set of parameter with where condition. it will automatically pick the parameter values from each row when update event occur. Please try below sample given in the MSDN and familiar with using SQL DataSource with gridviews.

[Modifying Data using the SqlDataSource Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkzs2t3h.aspx)

Comment: I considered that strategy but the problem is that this program is being optimized for speed of entry. So the user will be entering data down the columns rather quickly and I feel updating after each change would introduce a huge amount of latency.